# How to set build order/dependencies

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my workspace I have created 3 packages - 2 nodes and a library.  I use catkin_make to build, however it compiles the packages alphabetically; the nodes first then the library.  I get compiler errors because the library isn't built yet

Eg..

make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmrls_lib.so', needed by` catkin_ws/devel/lib/mrls_laser_range_finder/mrls_laser_range_finder_node'.  Stop

I can compile everything if I manually make the library first, eg..
catkin_make mrls_lib

I've added the library package to find_package() in CMakeLists.txt.  Have I missed something?

Frank

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79476/how-to-set-build-order/dependencies/) by [frank](https://answers.ros.org/users/5521/frank/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have a package dependency in the package.xml?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [frank](https://answers.ros.org/users/5521/frank/) on 2013-09-16**:
Ah ha!  That was it.  The <build_depend> tag.